# Incompatibility between AngularJS and Firefox

Tags: angularjs, firefox

My tables do not appear in Firefox. I saw that there is a compatibility problem with Firefox with AngularJS, what can I do?
Follow the code.

```
<table class="displayTagCss">
<thead>
    <th style="width: 50px;">&nbsp;</th>
    <th style="width: 50px;">Ordem</th>
    <th>Alertas</th>
    <th>Proposição</th>
    <th>Situação</th>
    <th style="width: 50px;">&nbsp;</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="proposicao in gruposSentencas['<c:out value='${grupo.idSentencaDePesquisa}' />']">
        <td style="text-align: center;">
            <img alt="Subir" title="Subir" ng-show="!$first" src="<html:rewrite page='/imagens/botao_subir.gif' />" ng-click="subirProposicao('<c:out value='${grupo.idSentencaDePesquisa}' />', $index)" />
            <img alt="Descer" title="Descer" ng-show="!$last" src="<html:rewrite page='/imagens/botao_descer.gif' />" ng-click="descerProposicao('<c:out value='${grupo.idSentencaDePesquisa}' />', $index)" />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">{{$index+1 }}</td>
        <td>
            <div class="hover" ng-if="(proposicao.alertas.length > 0) || proposicao.haPendencia">
                <img src="<html:rewrite page='/imagens/gfx/warning.png'/>" />
                <div class="appear">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="alerta_proposicao" ng-repeat="alerta in proposicao.alertas">{{ alerta }}</li>
                        <li class="alerta_proposicao" ng-if="proposicao.haPendencia"><span>Observações de fase: </span>{{proposicao.textoObservacao}}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>{{ proposicao.identificadorDaProposicao }}</td>
        <td>{{ proposicao.situacao }}</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;"><img src="<html:rewrite page='/imagens/chk_off.png' />" ng-click="removerProposicao('<c:out value='${grupo.idSentencaDePesquisa}' />', $index)" alt="Excluir" title="Excluir" /></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The 'thead' works, but the 'tbody' does not appear in Firefox.

Comment: I don't know if that helps, but you still need a `<tr>` around each row of cells in `<thead>`(are you using Angular with JSP? That's kind of edgy...)

Comment: It not worked :/

Yes, it's an old system (government), I haven't much choice kkk

Comment: I just checked that the problem is in:

<tr ng-repeat="proposicao in gruposSentencas['<c:out value='${grupo.idSentencaDePesquisa}' />']">


This section gives mozilla problem.

Comment: Is there any error log shown in the console? I understand that the `c:out` in your code prints a numerical value, so perhaps you need to drop the quotes around the array index like so: `[<c:out value='${grupo.idSentencaDePesquisa}' />]`